# Why can't I search with slash in the terminal?

Tags: command-line, manpage, configure, less

After opening any man page and pressing `/` there is no reaction from man. Although if I open files with vim everything works fine and I can search through them.

```
$ uname -v
#47~20.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 13 11:06:56 UTC 2021

$ update-alternatives --display pager
pager - auto mode
link best version is /usr/bin/less
link currently points to /usr/bin/less
link pager is /usr/bin/pager
slave pager.1.gz is /usr/share/man/man1/pager.1.gz
/bin/more - priority 50
slave pager.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/more.1.gz
/usr/bin/less - priority 77
slave pager.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/less.1.gz

$ readlink -f /usr/bin/pager 
/usr/bin/less
```

Comment: Does `/` forward search work in `less` itself, or is it broken in both `less` and `man`? Do you have any `man`-related variables in your environment (`$PAGER`, `$MANPAGER`)?

Comment: @steeldriver it was num lock issue. it was turned off.